# Does that border on monotheism?

Tags: religion, gods

The world was created, directly and indirectly, by the sun goddess. Even for the bad guys she is indirectly responsible. If she wanted, she could destroy the world without the other gods being able to do anything. -  Is that a little too powerful to be "just" the chief deity? I wonder if that borders on monotheism and I should downgrade her.

Comment: your world, your decision. It's not something we can provide an objective answer here.

Comment: It can hardly border on monotheism. Monotheism assumes there is only one god. If there are other gods & goddesses than the Sun Goddess, then it's polytheism pure & simple. So wonder no more. Your Sun Goddess is simply very powerful.

Comment: Zeus was perfectly able to do much mischief without the other gods being able to do much about it. Actually, several of the gods of the classical world were quite able to do much mischief without anybody being able to stop them. For example, consider the Trojan cycle: Eris, Aphrodite, Athena, Poseidon etc. are free agents, with Zeus utterly unable to stop the trainwreck.

Comment: @LightEye -- More to the point: "monotheism" is a form of religious practice or persuasion which admits the worship of one single deity and whether other deities exist or not. It's a matter of how people approach the question of the divine.  Your query is cosmogonical in nature, involving as it does the creation of the universe; and also relates the creation to the relative powers & abilities of the various divinities that exist. The two concepts do not presuppose any kind of causal relationship. In other words, just because the Sun goddess is creator & destroyer doesn't make her (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) the only goddess in the pantheon.  You already admit to the existence of other gods.  By definition, she's not alone!  Your query is in serious need of work to address this issue! Am voting to close because it's pretty clear you don't have a grasp (yet) on what your actual question involves.

Answer (score 2):

While @L.Dutch is right and it is ultimately your decision this may give you some guidelines to work from:

[Monotheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotheism) is a religious definition, which by its nature cannot be applied to a [pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon_(religion)) of gods.

That doesn't really answer the question though so how about this; if the Sun Goddess is being worshiped as the sole deity with the rest of the pantheon being treated as less than godlike in power, think [angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel) or [jinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn) powerful by human standards but definitely not gods. Then you have a monotheistic situation. On the other hand if the rest of the pantheon are godlike in power but specialised and subservient to the Sun Goddess, think [Ares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares) and [Artemis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis) compared to [Zeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus) then she's a chief deity in a true pantheon.

Comment: Thank you. That pretty much answers my question.

Comment: Ares subservient to Zeus? That's *citation needed*. As for Artemis, when did she even *interact* with Zeus? (Except in the well-known [scene in Offenbach's *Orphée aux enfers*](https://youtu.be/g6V2Iz_dy8I?t=3862) where she is one of the leaders of the mini rebellion against the neverending bland food -- *Plus de nectar! plus d'ambroisie!* -- and the moral hypocrisy of Zeus the philanderer pretending to be outraged by Pluto's abduction of Euridice.)

Comment: @AlexP Yeah subservient isn't quite the right word for what I'm driving at but it's the closest one I can think of. They have relatively narrow spheres of influence/responsibility and sit below the King of Olympus, hierarchically if not in terms of power or ambition.

Comment: @Ash: That's purely ceremonial. In practical terms, Eris was perfectly able to start the entire conflict driving the Trojan cycle; during the same cycle, Aphrodite was dead-set against Athena (= Zeus's protegee); Athena herself finagled Zeus out of his vow of eternal punishment for Prometheus; Hera even lead a full scale rebellion against Zeus; and *Zeus himself* rose to power by overthrowing (and castrating!) his own father and former top god.

Comment: @AlexP And yet Zeus, Poseidon, and Hades are described as being of greater power and/or consequence than the rest of their pantheon. Said pantheon is composed of individually powerful members who are all undoubtedly gods, they all wield vast, potentially world altering, amounts of power but Zeus is still first among them, the chief deity.

Comment: Your Greek example has some issues (the gods that were prominent has nothing to do with power but with influence - some things are more important to humans....also both Zeus & Cronus killed the head god to become the head) but the idea is sound and it has been done before. Such as in Tolkien's work, the god [Eru Ilúvatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eru_Il%C3%BAvatar) with the lesser divine beings the Ainur (*The Silmarillion* even has a good explanation for this)

Comment: @JGreenwell Yes the Greek pantheon generally has plenty of issues, in more ways than one. The Ainur are angels, not gods, their powers are sharply limited, there are tasks they are charged to complete and things that only Eru can do. A true pantheon is composed of beings who may not be at the same "power level" but who all share the similar potential capabilities.

Comment: Yes, hence - no you cannot have a pantheon with such a level of in-balance (or at least based on the historical model given, or Greek myths) but you can do something with lesser divine beings. Also, note, the Roman model was more structured in terms of order (if not power) but you then have to deal with beings like Janus and where they fit in a hierarchy, Norse certainly works better with Odin but then Fenrir will kill him, & there are Eastern models which definitely have more powerful gods over others (though, again, this is usually a set of primary gods over a single "all-powerful" one).

Comment: or basically, I agree with LDutch that it is not answerable as it stands because I would need more clarification on a number of items to determine the best historic or fantasy model (or they would just have to make it up to fit their needs which is too story based and where it now stands)